# Trouble deleting arrays (an error unknown to me)

Tags: c++, arrays, destructor, allocation

I have a structure that is supposed to "breathe" as its being used. Its a matrix of pointers.
(BigInt is some type, doesn't matter what it is...)

```
BigInt ***directory;
```

it is initialized this way (the size of matrix is M*M):

```
directory = new BigInt**[M];
for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    directory[i] = NULL;
```

and it is expanded, when needed, this way:

```
partition = ...;
directory[partition] = new BigInt*[M];
for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    directory[partition][i] = NULL;
```

And destroyed this way (this method is called from the destructor of the class that has BigInt*** directory as a field):

```
void del() {
    for(int p=0;p<M;p++)
        if(directory[p]!=NULL) {
            for(int o=0;o<M;o++)
                if(directory[p][o]!=NULL)
                    delete directory[p][o];
        }

    for(int p=0;p<M;p++)
        if(directory[p]!=NULL)
            delete directory[p];

    delete directory;
}
```

At the end of my program, however, my program breaks (triggers a breakpoint) in dbgheap.c, at:

```
/***
*int _CrtIsValidHeapPointer() - verify pointer is from 'local' heap
*
*Purpose:
*       Verify pointer is not only a valid pointer but also that it is from
*       the 'local' heap. Pointers from another copy of the C runtime (even in the
*       same process) will be caught.
*
*Entry:
*       const void * pUserData     - pointer of interest
*
*Return:
*       TRUE - if valid and from local heap
*       FALSE otherwise
*
*******************************************************************************/
extern "C" _CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(
        const void * pUserData
        )
{
        if (!pUserData)
            return FALSE;

        if (!_CrtIsValidPointer(pHdr(pUserData), sizeof(_CrtMemBlockHeader), FALSE))
            return FALSE;

        return HeapValidate( _crtheap, 0, pHdr(pUserData) );
}
```

The same breakpoint occurs when I attempt to deallocate the memory by calling del() or when I attempt to delete a single array (when the matrix is "breathing") like this:

```
int p = ...;
delete directory[p];
```

I've never occurred this kind of error, and the program works fine if I don't deallocate my memory.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<BigInt>>>`?  Then you get no leaks.  Even better, a single `std::vector<BigInt>` and simulate a 3d array by adjusting the indices accordingly.  Triple-star (`***`) programming in C++ is not a necessity in this day and age.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can't use vector, I've left out some specification because it's not important :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allocating arrays using new[], but deleting them with the delete operator. If you allocate something using new[], you should delete it using delete[], otherwise you trigger undefined behavior.

For example, you should replace this code:

```
delete directory[p];
```

with this:

```
delete[] directory[p];
```

The same applies to all other occurrences of delete in the code you posted.

Comment: this is what happens when you code in Java for half a year... Thanks! :)